# Maximo Application does't update after Maximo anywehere have made change

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

When changing the status of a work order in the Anywhere mobile application, I have this error message at the eclispe console, during synchronization with the maximo application:

> "Backend response content type 'application/json 'did not match the
> expected content type' text/html ',

continue prossesing the response. The request and response headers and body: request:

> /maximo/os/oslcwodetail/_Q01SLzIzNjIzMg-- {"spi: status": "INPRG",
> "spi_wm: statusdate": "2020-08-03T11: 11: 31 + 01: 00"} ".

Can you help me to solve this issue?